# SQL Table UPDATE by row with days per month

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-update

SQL Server 2005:

I'm attempting to create a table that looks like this:

```
                         JAN  |   FEB    |   March .......Dec   | YTD
Total Volume: 

Days in Month:

Gallons per day AVG:
```

Three rows with description on left, 13 columns (one for each month and year to date total).
I know how to populate the total volume per month. What would I use for days per month and average? I'd like the days per month to show either the complete number of days if it is a past month or current completed days if its the current month.

Comment: SQL Server has built-in date functions that can be used to calculate these values.   Have you tried them?

Answer (score 0):

You are pivoting the data, so you want the results in columns.  You can do this by using direct calculation.  Here is an example for the first three months:

```
select 'Days In Month' as col1,
       (case when month(getdate()) < 1 then 0
             when month(getdate()) = 1 then day(getdate())
             else 31
        end) as Jan,
       (case when month(getdate()) < 2 then 0
             when month(getdate()) = 2 then day(getdate())
             when year(getdate()) % 4 = 0 then 29
             else 28
        end) as Feb,
       (case when month(getdate()) < 3 then 0
             when month(getdate()) = 3 then day(getdate())
             else 31
        end) as Mar,
```